# VBA - printing wrong value from range

Tags: vba, excel

I have working code that I altered to work with a textbox button. Everything works well except I am trying to print from a range that grabs the header "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):" and prints the cell to the right of that to my mastefile.

**ISSUE:**
It works beautifully with my original code that opens multiple files to print out information. However, trying to apply it to a textbox where I type in a file name, it prints out the word HOLDER where it is supposed to print the tool name, ie "TDS-2343298". I cannot figure out from where it is even grabbing the word HOLDER let alone why my range is not working properly with this textbox when it works in my multiple files code. The line that seems to be printing the wrong thing is this area *(in section (5) of my code)*:

```
If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
```

Any ideas please?
**EDIT:**
**The problem is it is reading from the wrong sheet so I need to switch the active sheet...any advice on how to do that given this code?**

***Summary of what code does:***

**USING TEXTBOX:** Type a file name into the textbox which searches a folder and opens up that file, then gets important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL" by searching for the header and and printing all the info under that header into one excel document, masterfile. It also prints the file name into column 4 and the name of the "Tooling Data Sheet" to column 1.

**RUNNING THROUGH MULTIPLE FILES:**
Loops through folder to open files and get important info from the columns of names "HOLDER" and "CUTTING TOOL"by searching for the header and and printing all the info under that header into one excel document, masterfile. It also prints the file name into column 4 and the name of the "Tooling Data Sheet" to column 1.

**FULL CODE USING TEXTBOX:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


'Set folder path where the file is located
Const TDS_PATH = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

'Clear out any info on current page
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:D7557").Clear

'TextBox1.Text = ".xlsx"
'TextBox1.Font.Italic = True

'input checking
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please enter a file to search for")
End If

'Dim WB As Workbook
'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
'Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet


'If the File we are searching for exists in the path
If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then

    'Disable screen updating for performance/aesthetics
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Open the workbook we searched for (ReadOnly)
    Workbooks.Open TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text, ReadOnly:=True
    Set WrkBk = Workbooks.Open(TDS_PATH & TextBox1.Text)
    'Set WrkBk = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)
    'Workbooks.Open objFile.Name


    'Copy the range we are interested in



    'Dim OpenSht As Worksheet


    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim f As String
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, hc5 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)

    i = 2

        'Set WB = Workbooks
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

        'Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.NameUpdateLinks:=0)

        Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
        If Not hc Is Nothing Then

            Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
            If dict.count > 0 Then
                Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'add the values to the master list, column 3
                d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
            End If
        Else
            StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
        End If
'(4)
        'find HOLDER on the source sheet
        Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
        If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then
            Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
            'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
            If dict.count > 0 Then
                Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                'add the values to the master list, column 2
                d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
            End If
            'End If
        Else
            StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
        End If

'(5)
    With ws
        'print TDS information
                'print the file name to Column 1
                StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = TextBox1.Text

                'print TDS name from J1 cell to Column 4
                    With WrkBk
                    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                        If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                            Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                        Else
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO TDS VALUE!"
                        End If
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                    End With
'(6)
        'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
        WrkBk.Close 'SaveChanges:=False

        'Not StartSht = Close
'            If ActiveWorkbook <> StartSht Then
'                ActiveWorkbook.Close False
'            End If
    End With


End If

'(7)
'turn screen updating back on
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

    'Re-enable screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Let the user know if the file is not found
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("File not found!")
End If

End Sub

'Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus()
'    TextBox1.Text = ""
'    TextBox1.Font.Italic = False
'End Sub

'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function

'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function


'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

**FULL WORKING CODE THAT RUNS THROUGH MULTIPLE FILES:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

    Const ROW_HEADER As Long = 10

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim f As String
    Dim StartSht As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer, erow As Integer
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Long
    Dim hc As Range, hc1 As Range, hc2 As Range, hc3 As Range, hc4 As Range, d As Range
    Dim TDS As Range

    Set StartSht = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

    'turn screen updating off - makes program faster
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'location of the folder in which the desired TDS files are
    MyFolder = "C:\Users\trembos\Documents\TDS\progress\"

    'find the headers on the sheet
    Set hc1 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("B1"), "HOLDER")
    Set hc2 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("C1"), "CUTTING TOOL")
    Set hc4 = HeaderCell(StartSht.Range("A1"), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")

    'create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyFolder)
    i = 2


    'loop through directory file and print names
'(1)
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 3)) = "xls" Or LCase(Left(Right(objFile.Name, 4), 3)) = "xls" Then
'(2)
            'Open folder and file name, do not update links
            Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & objFile.Name, UpdateLinks:=0)
            Set ws = WB.ActiveSheet
'(3)
                'find CUTTING TOOL on the source sheet
                Set hc = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "CUTTING TOOL")
                If Not hc Is Nothing Then

                    Set dict = GetValues(hc.Offset(1, 0), "SplitMe")
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                    'add the values to the master list, column 3
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
'(4)
                'find HOLDER on the source sheet
                Set hc3 = HeaderCell(ws.Cells(ROW_HEADER, 1), "HOLDER")
                If Not hc3 Is Nothing Then
                    Set dict = GetValues(hc3.Offset(1, 0))
                    'If InStr(ROW_HEADER, "HOLDER") <> "" Then
                    If dict.count > 0 Then
                        'add the values to the master list, column 2
                        Set d = StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc1.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                        d.Resize(dict.count, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(dict.items)
                    End If
                    'End If
                Else
                    StartSht.Cells(Rows.count, hc2.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "NO 'CUTTING TOOL' PRESENT!"
                End If
'(5)
            With WB
               'print TDS information
                'For Each ws In .Worksheets

                    'print the file name to Column 4


                    StartSht.Cells(i, 4) = objFile.Name

                    'Search for "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", move one column to the right, print info to masterfile column 1
                    'If Not TDS Is Nothing Then
                    'ValueToFind = "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):"

'                    'Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
'                    If Not IsError(Application.Match("TOOLING DATA SHEET(TDS):", Range("A1:K1"), 0)) Then
'                    'If Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Then
'                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = ""
'                    Else
'                        Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
'                        StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
'                    End If

'                    Dim p As Long
'                    With ws
'                        If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Rows(ROW_HEADER), "TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):")) Then
'                            p = Application.Match("TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", .Rows(ROW_HEADER), 0)
'                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = p
'                        Else
'                            StartSht.Cells(i, 1) = 1
'                        End If
'                    End With


                    With ws
                    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
                        If Not Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
                            Set TDS = Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Offset(, 1)
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = TDS
                        Else
                            StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)) = "NO TDS VALUE!"
                        End If
                        i = GetLastRowInSheet(StartSht) + 1
                    End With




                    'End If

                'move to next file
                'Next ws
'(6)
                'close, do not save any changes to the opened files
                .Close SaveChanges:=False
            End With
        End If
    '(7)

    'move to next file
    Next objFile
    'turn screen updating back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'brings the viewer to the top of the masterfile
End Sub



'(8)
'get all unique column values starting at cell c
Function GetValues(ch As Range, Optional vSplit As Variant) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim v
    Dim spl As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    For Each c In ch.Parent.Range(ch, ch.Parent.Cells(Rows.count, ch.Column).End(xlUp)).Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 And Not dict.exists(v) Then

            'exclude any info after ";"
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ";")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            'exclude any info after ","
            If Not IsMissing(vSplit) Then
            spl = Split(v, ",")
            v = spl(0)
            End If

            dict.Add c.Address, v
        End If
    Next c
    Set GetValues = dict
End Function

'(9)
'find a header on a row: returns Nothing if not found
Function HeaderCell(rng As Range, sHeader As String) As Range
    Dim rv As Range, c As Range
    For Each c In rng.Parent.Range(rng, rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Row, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells
        'copy cell value if it contains some string "holder" or "cutting tool"
        If InStr(c.Value, sHeader) <> 0 Then
            Set rv = c
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
    Set HeaderCell = rv
End Function
'(10)
Function GetLastRowInColumn(theWorksheet As Worksheet, col As String)
    With theWorksheet
        GetLastRowInColumn = .Range(col & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function


'(11)
Function GetLastRowInSheet(theWorksheet As Worksheet)
Dim ret
    With theWorksheet
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            ret = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            ret = 1
        End If
    End With
    GetLastRowInSheet = ret
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code example it is impossible to tell which workbook & worksheet is being searched. You are also running the search twice. Change your code to how it is shown below, using the relevant values for "book_name.xlsm" and "sheet_name".

```
Dim headingFound As Range
Set headingFound = Workbooks("book_name.xlsm").Worksheets("sheet_name")Range("A1:K1").Find(What:="TOOLING DATA SHEET (TDS):", LookAt:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not headingFound Is Nothing Then
    Set TDS = headingFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
    StartSht.Range(StartSht.Cells(i, 1), StartSht.Cells(GetLastRowInColumn(StartSht, "C"), 1)).Value = TDS.Value
```